# ¿Cómo hago un relación de muchos a muchos en Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

Quiero agregar un data de la siguiente manera:

```
{
   "nombre": "Perro",
   "precio": 2000,
   "ingredientes": [
       {
           "id": 3
        },
        {
          "id": 6
        }
   ]
}
```

De tal forma q' al momento de agregar un producto, me relaciones los ingredientes con los ya existentes.

```
package com.semillero.restaurante.rest;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.semillero.restaurante.dao.ProductosDAO;
import com.semillero.restaurante.model.Productos;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("products")
public class ProductosRest {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductosDAO dao;
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<Productos> getAll() {
        return (List<Productos>) dao.findAll();
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public Productos saveData(@RequestBody Productos producto) {
        return dao.save(producto);
    }
    
    @PutMapping
    public Productos updateData(@RequestBody Productos producto) {
        try {
            dao.findById(producto.getId()).get();
            return dao.save(producto);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteById(@PathVariable("id") Integer Id) {
        dao.deleteById(Id);
    }

}
```

Y el Dao:

```
package com.semillero.restaurante.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.semillero.restaurante.model.Productos;

public interface ProductosDAO extends CrudRepository<Productos, Integer> {

}
```

Comment: faltó incluir tu dao, sin él hay una cantidad no polinomial de posibilidades de formas de configurar la base de datos y de consultarla

Comment: @RuslanLópez Listo

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar @ManyToMany en tu clase Productos?

Comment: Si,  solo se me agrega  por nombre de ingrediente y no por id  que es como lo requiero..

Comment: ¿qué framework usas pra conectarte a la BDD? Hibernate?

Comment: Ni idea,  la conexion es con el spring boot, simplemente paso los datos en el "application.properties" pero de seguro no ningun framework adicional

Comment: Añade tu ``application.properties`` para poder ver los datos de configuración.

Comment: Creo que primero debes de averiguar que estas usando de ORM podría ser hibernate, JPA, mybatis, etc. Que spring boot se integre con esas tecnologías ya es muy distinto, ya que spring no es un ORM y no soporta eso, es la integración con ORM lo que permite eso.

Answer (score 3):

Con SpringBoot puedes usar JPA o Spring Data JPA. Tus clases deben ser algo así, he puesto explícitamente las foreign keys con varias opciones para que las puedas ver mejor y elegir la que mas te guste.

Fijate que uso **Set** en lugar de **List**, ya que JPA e Hibernate son bastante mas ineficientes al eliminar objetos de una colección ordenada que en un conjunto.

Además @ManyToMany tiene la opción de que le configures el modo de obtener los datos (Lazy;Parcial o Eager;Completo) con esta propiedad *fetch = FetchType.LAZY*:

```
@Entity
public class Producto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    String nombre;
    int precio;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ingredientes", 
               joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name="fk_producto") },
               inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_ingrediente") })    
    Set<Ingrediente> ingredientes;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Ingrediente.class,
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    private Set<Ingrediente> ingredientes2;

    // getter & setters ...
}

    
@Entity
public class Ingrediente {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    String nombre;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productos", 
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<Producto> productos;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Producto.class, 
                mappedBy = "ingredientes2", 
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Producto> productos2;
    
    // getter & setters ...
}
```